# Permutations maintaining order of some elements

Tags: python, algorithm

Looking for an implementation in `Python` but I can probably translate from anything.

If I have the `string` `"cats   "`, which is the word cats followed by four spaces, how can I find all of the possible permutations **that maintain the order of the word cats**. That is I'm not looking for any permutations where a is the first actual letter, or t, etc., but instead all of the possible arrangements of white space in between the letters in `cats`.

Some examples:

```
"cats    "
"c ats   "
"  cat  s"
"c a t s "
" c a t s"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution, not an algorithm :) The algorithm is buried in the implementation of `itertools.combinations` (but see below for an implementation without builtin library functions).

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations

def assign(v, p):
  v[p[0]] = p[1]
  return v

def interp(word, letter, size):
  return (''.join(reduce(assign, zip(comb, word), [letter] * size))
          for comb in combinations(range(size), len(word)))
```

Example (using dots instead of spaces to make them more visible):

```
>>> print('\n'.join(interp("cats", ".", 6)))
cats..
cat.s.
cat..s
ca.ts.
ca.t.s
ca..ts
c.ats.
c.at.s
c.a.ts
c..ats
.cats.
.cat.s
.ca.ts
.c.ats
..cats
```

It's actually pretty easy to implement `combinations` (but why bother, since it is already defined?). Here's one solution which does way too much tuple concatenation to be efficient, but demonstrates the algorithm:

```
def combs(vec, count, start=0):
  if count == 0:
    yield ()
  else:
    for i in range(start, len(vec) + 1 - count):
      for c in combs(vec, count - 1, i + 1):
        yield((i,) + c)
```

In other words, for each possible first position, choose that and complete the combination with the remaining positions. Similarly, you could directly implement the desired function:

```
def interp(word, letter, size):
  if len(word) == 0:
    yield letter * size
  else:
    for i in range(size + 1 - len(word)):
      for comb in interp(word[1:], letter, size - i - 1):
        yield letter * i + word[0] + comb
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to upvote this because it's so dense, but the question did ask for an implementation, so.

Comment: @blender: If I had more time, I could make it sparser :)

Comment: hm, even after looking at this for approximatly 5 minutes I still don't know if I posted an identical answer or if they differ :) But they do look similar at least.

Comment: @MSeifert: They're essentially the same. I changed `map` to a list comprehension, but I don't know if that makes it any less "dense"

Comment: Yes, now I can see it too. `map`, with `lambda` and `reduce` with an inplace-update helper function made it a bit hard to follow at first. :)

Comment: @MSeifert: yeah, `assign` is a bit ugly. Shame that there isn't a builtin update function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the combinations where the 4 letters should be quite easily - with `combinations` from the `itertools` module.

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations(range(len("cats    ")), len("cats")):
    # comb is a 4 tuple containing the indices where to insert the letters "cats".
```

Then you simply need to insert them at the correct place and join it:

```
empty = [" "]*len("cats    ")

for comb in combinations(range(len("cats    ")), len("cats")):
    newstring = list(empty)  # make a copy
    for idx, letter in zip(comb, "cats"):  # insert the letters
        newstring[idx] = letter
    print(''.join(newstring))  # join and print

cats    
cat s   
cat  s  
cat   s 
cat    s
ca ts   
ca t s  
ca t  s 
ca t   s
ca  ts  
ca  t s 
ca  t  s
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion.

If you have `n` spaces, first choose how many spaces come before the first letter. Call it `k`. Then call your function with `n-k` spaces and the remaining letters.

Answer (score 0):

For string "cats" you have five places to insert spaces (before, after and between letters). Essentially this is problem of generation of all integer partitions of number 4 into 5 integer parts, including zero parts.

On of the simplest methods to generate such partitions is recursive: at every level of recursion insert space into the current placeholder, and call next level, and call next level without inderting (of possible)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t this work? It’s not an algorithm but it should serve your purpose:

```
def check_word(word):
    if word.replace(" ", "") == "cats":
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: in this case just a `word.replace(" ","")` is better and simple

Comment: and this doesn't answer the question at all. OP didn't ask how to remove spaces...

Comment: @Copperfield Wow, for some reason I was thinking that `.replace` would only replace the first occurrence. I'll change it

Comment: @JulienBernu It does; removes the spaces and then checks against the wanted string

Comment: This is extremely inefficient since you are looping over all permutations to then throw away most of them...

Comment: @JulienBernu True

Comment: oh, this remind me of of me first examen of algorithm... back to the point, you can return the result of the comparison `return a==b`

Answer (score 0):

If you find the permutations, you can filter them out by regex:

```
import itertools
import re

string = 'cats    '
pattern = ' *c *a *t *s *'
matcher = re.compile(pattern)

perms = itertools.permutations(string)
se = set([''.join(p) for p in perms])
li = list(filter(matcher.search, se))
```

Prints:

```
['   cats ',
 'c a t  s',
 'ca  t  s',
   ....
 'c   ats ',
 '  ca ts ',
 ' ca t  s',
 ' c at s ',
 'ca t   s',
 'ca  ts  ']
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient since you are looping over all permutations to then throw away most of them...

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
str_in = "cats   "
str_in_nospace = str_in.replace(" ", "")
p = itertools.permutations(str_in, r=None)
for itm in p:
    str_curent = ''.join(itm)
    str_curent_nospace = str_curent.replace(" ", "")
    if str_curent_nospace == str_in_nospace:
        print str_curent
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient since you are looping over all permutations to then throw away most of them...